# Join statement...how do do ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql

I have the following LEFT JOIN statement (though probably also applies to even a simpler SELECT statement):

```
SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.c = t1.c WHERE t1.m LIKE 'captain%' GROUP BY     
t1.c ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

The results get returned but they are not ordered by t2.date DESC...I imagine this is due to having the GROUP BY statement in there. How can I group the results AND order them?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your query in a subquery and then use ORDER BY.

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (SELECT * 
  FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.c = t1.c 
  WHERE t1.m LIKE 'captain%' 
  GROUP BY t1.c DESC LIMIT 0,10) l1
ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

In normal SQL it would not even be allowed to `ORDER BY t2.date` because you aren't grouping on it and you are not using an aggregate function on it, so you can't select it.

Anyway, as MySQL just picks values from the rows in an undefined manner and afterwards sorts them, the `t2.date` column in your results should be sorted. Please show some actual output.

Comment: This is probably just my unfamiliarity with MySQL, but what the heck is the result of doing SELECT * while GROUPing on a single column? The first thing I'd expect is "<ColumnX> is invalid in the SELECT list because it is not contained in an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"... Can you not just add t2.date to the GROUP BY?

Comment: @ginius No, it does not ignore the ORDER BY. I doubt the t2.date values are not in order, that's why you should show them.

Comment: @djacobson: You are right to expect this, but MySQL (in default mode) works a bit different: It picks undefined (random) values for those columns.

Comment: [So I see](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html). Fascinating! I've got to say, I'm prejudiced against MySQL's behavior in this case, regardless of Bouman's argument (see link). :)